# How to live edit CSS for dynamic javascript elements usign developer tools Style Editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to style javascript element that is available only then I use the mouse. When I try to select element using Firefox Development Toolbar, it disappears.

Is there a way to inspect elements that are dynamically generated?

I tried digging thru the CSS, but that is a very slow process when I don't know how the

P.S. This is unbelievable. I asked this exact Q on Webmasters forum and they closed the Q and told me to ask on SuperUsers forum, so I went there and asked, only to get the Q closed. Thus I came here to ask the same. Hope someone could help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the behavior to reproduce? If it's just a matter of using the "Toggle Element State" option on the dev toolbar because you're just hovering something vs something like a JS event listener listening for mousedown and triggering something else? As it sits I'm not picturing the scenario very well so a reproducible example would better explain your issue.

Comment: Example is here: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ on the bottom you have working example. When you write, say, "a" in the box there is a dropdown. I need to style that dropdown, but it is dynamic and I can't catch correct classes to style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your response, easy peasy. Just get the dropdown to appear, right-click -> inspect, it will take you directly to the html in the DOM that has `style="display:none"` you can just change to `display: block` in the dev tools, or just add this css selector to override it somewhere in your css and style away, cheers;

```
.ui-autocomplete { display: block !important }
```

Comment: I feel dumb now. I constantly tried to inspect parent element... Thanks!

Comment: Anyone who says they haven't been there before (or will be again) is a liar lol, cheers!